# how can I create a tooltip only when we use mouseover of button in an item in vis.js timeline

Tags: angularjs, timeline, vis.js

I used vis.js timeline to create a timeline . I need to create tooltip when mouse over into button only not the whole item . I applicate title . the tooltip appears but It was applicated on the whole item . I need a tooltip appplicated only when we mouse over the button not the whole item .

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "template" function in the vis timeline config. In the template function you can modify what the item template should look like. There you can add a button and then add event listeners.

```
template: function(item) {
  var itemTmp = document.createElement('div');
  itemTmp.innerHTML = item.content + ' ';
  var btn = document.createElement('button');
  btn.innerText = 'Hover Me!';
  btn.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    btn.innerText = 'Done!';
  });
  btn.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    btn.innerText = 'Hover Me!';
  });
  itemTmp.appendChild(btn);
  return itemTmp;
}
```

Full example:
http://jsfiddle.net/tagisen/qp3dwrzn/

Hope this helps